# javascript variable pointers inside functions

Tags: javascript, function, variables, variable-assignment

So here's a strange one:

```
var a = true;
function f(v){ v = !v; }        //can this function actually change a?
f(a);   //a is still true..
```

The function obviously changes only the value if it's internal *`v`* variable.

I came across this working on an application that should change the values of properties of `DOM` Elements dynamically at run time. So ideally there should be a function that takes a property as an argument and reassigns it, right?

for clarity - I am actually trying to assign new values to DOM element's attributes at runtime: I have a reflector application that iterates through members of objects and I want it to be able to change the value of properties that it comes across, so the f function would belong to a BooleanSwitch constructor function that builds a booleanSwitch object for every boolean type property in the reflected object. the booleanSwitch can be a simple button on screen. I want to be able to change the value of the actual property of the object at hand just by clicking the button..
can anyone think of a way to do this?

Any thoughts are appriciated..

Comment: Are you sure the function you came across didn't have a `return` statement, or accept an Object argument?

Comment: ...and are you sure the function was named `switch`? This would not be a valid function name.

Comment: Sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: Please update your code as already pointed out. Your question is not a problem according to the code, as long as you are not trying to assign any value to variable `a` inside the function body, you're just assigning the variable `v` passed as an argument.

Comment: @..607 I came across the problem,not the code.but ur right aboat the switch keyword, I've fixed that.

Comment: @dbf - I am trying to assign a value to a.

Comment: @Matt Ball - think of a situation where you don't know what 'a' would be. I am actually trying to assign new values to DOM element at runtime: I have a reflector application that iterates through members of objects and I want it to be able to change the value of properties that it comes across, so the switch (or f) function would belong to a BooleanSwitch constructor function that builds a booleanSwitch object for every boolean type property in the reflected object. the booleanSwitch is a simple button. I want to be able to change the value of the **actual property** by clicking the button

Comment: @IdoOfir read about _pass by reference_ and _pass by value_ [here](http://www.snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass/). (my previous comment thought that you were not, sorry about that. I realised now you're trying to assign `a` passing as an argument, but the value is primitive, which will be sent _by value_ as `AndreMeinhold` stated)

Comment: @dbf cheers for the link, things are clearer. though not yet solved.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Primitive values are passed *by value*. You do pass a *boolean value* into that function, so it can't change the value of the variable `a`, declared outside.

Answer (score 1):

Objects (arrays, functions) are passed as reference. All other types (int, string etc) are copied.

In your example, 'v' is a copy of 'a', so 'a' does not change.

You need to return a value from the switch function, and assign it to a. eg:

```
function switch(v)
{
//do something
return v;
}

a = switch(a);
```

Comment: yes, this would obviously work, but my real problem is that I don't know what 'a' is. this would only be known at run time. so I can't hardcode the assignment into 'a', I've edited the question for clarity..thnx.

Answer (score 1):

The function must return a value.

```
function switchValue(v){ 
  return !v;
}        

var a = true;
switchValue(a);
```

This is because of JavaScript referencing feature. If you pass in the variable and dont return it, the variable will only change locally. You have to specifically return it, if you want it to be changed.

Comment: And function `switch` magically knows where the variable `a` is? And this code will not run ..

Comment: change the function name to something else other than switch(), for example switchValue(v)

Answer (score 0):

so just figured out a nice way to do this:

booleans, as other primitive values are passed by value, but objects are passed by reference..
the boolean value passed to function f can be passed by reference if it belongs to an object.
so:

```
var a = true;
function f(v, z){
    v[z] = !v[z];
{
f(window, "a");
```

which looks a bit strange and is still hard coded, but can be made to work dynamically with properties when iterating through objects.

in my real application it looks something like this:

```
function BooleanSwitch(obj, property){
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.onclick = function(){
        obj[property] = !obj[property];
    }
    return btn;
}

function reflect(obj){
    for(member in obj){
        switch(typeof(obj[member])){
            case "boolean":
                var booleanSwitch = BooleanSwitch(obj, member);
                document.body.appendChild(booleanSwitch);  //or whatever..
                break;
            case "string": //..other stuff..
        }
    }
}

reflect(document);
```

this will create a boolean switch for each enumerable boolean property of the document object.
when you click this button it changes the actual property of the document.